# JDA getting all channels

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I need to get all channels that my bot can see into a string array like
{#general, #memes}. How do I do this. I have scrolled through the JDA class methods and have found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this, and without any code it is quite hard to help you.

First, if you have a `JDA` instance you could do
`jda.getGuildById("your_guild_id").getChannels();`

Second, if you have an `event` from a `onMessageReceived` event you could do: `event.getGuild().getChannels()`

```
     @Override
     public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event)
     {
         System.out.println(String.join(",", event.getGuild().getChannels()));
     }
```

Third, if you have an `event` from a `onReady` event you could do: `event.getJDA()getGuildById("your_guild_id").getChannels()`

```
     @Override
     public void onReady(ReadyEvent event)
     {
         System.out.println(String.join(",", event.getJDA().getGuildById("your_guild_id").getChannels()));
     }
```

Here is an example:

```
public class Main implements EventListener{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault("YOUR_BOT_TOKEN");
            builder.addEventListeners(new Main());
            builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReady(ReadyEvent event){
        JDA jda = event.getJDA();
        Guild guild = jda.getGuildById("YOUR_GUILD_ID");
        System.out.println(String.join(",", guild.getChannels());
    }
}
```

Please post some code of what you have if this doesn't help.

Comment: No, this helps so much. One thing though, how do I get Guild ID?

Comment: @SecretAgent guild.getGuildId(). JDA is properly organized with objects. If you want the guildId, it's just guild.getId(). If your IDE provides autocompletion, when you put a dot after the guild object it should show you all available operations.

Comment: @SecretAgent To find your guild id in discord itself, please see this link: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-